# Django template tags: using forloop.first tag within conditional tag

Tags: django, django-templates, formset, detailview

This is a continuation of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758831/linking-to-other-foreign-model-with-detailview-and-formset-in-django/50764652#50764652) in which I use django-formset and detailview.

Let's see a customer orders an item on June 3rd. How can I retrieve the latest price of that item before June 3rd, which is $2?

[image]

I have the following django template tags, but it returns $4.

```
{% for cartitem_ in object.model_customercartitem_set.all %}
    {% for pricerow_ in cart_item.item_name.model_itemprice_set.all %}
        {% if price_row.timestamp|date:"U" <= object.timestamp|date:"U" %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                {{ price_row.item_price }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Perhaps I have used *forloop.first* tag incorrectly, so what should the right tag be? Any other solution besides template tag works too.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should encode this logic in the *view* not in a template. It is a common misconception that a template should be used to calculate things. A template should actually only be used to *render* things in a *nice* way.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to encode this in views, but to no avail when django-formset is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You missed an {% endif %}

```
{% for cartitem_ in object.model_customercartitem_set.all %}
    {% for pricerow_ in cart_item.item_name.model_itemprice_set.all %}
        {% if price_row.timestamp|date:"U" <= object.timestamp|date:"U" %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                {{ price_row.item_price }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %} <!-- here -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Apology that I forgot to include this on the original post. Thanks. I am still unable to get the correct item price even after the revision.

Comment: I would just print {{ price_row.item_price }} without the {% if forloop.first %} part, and see what is the output, then figure out what to do next.